# How do I determine at what angle to move to intercept another object moving along a circular path?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, kinematics, rotational-kinematics, rotation

I came across this issue on my own. This is not a homework problem.

Two people (you and someone else) are running along a circular track, with known positions in relation to each other, and known tangential velocities. However, you decide you want to meet this other person, and want to run in a straight line to meet them. Assuming they are confined to a circular path, you can run at any angle you'd like, and both of you maintain constant linear velocities, how do you, in general, determine at what angle to run so that your paths intersect?

Example: You're running at 1$\frac{m}{s}$ exactly opposite someone else running with a tangential linear velocity of 1$\frac{m}{s}$ on the other side of a circle with a radius of 10 meters.

Analysis: The circumference is 20π meters. If you run straight towards where they are initially, you will take 20 seconds to reach where they were. However, they will be 31.83% (or $100*\frac{20}{20π}$, which equals $100*π^{-1}$) of the circumference of the circle away from you at that point. If you aim more towards where they were going, I have no idea how far you would have to aim to find a location where your particular velocity and their circular motion will meet.

I've actually faced almost this exact problem in real life before, so it's kind of interesting how much math is involved here.

Comment: In your example, are both people traveling either clockwise or counter-clockwise around the circle?

Comment: I ended up figuring it out on my own. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4397469/physical-model-how-do-you-solve-for-a-variable-in-the-argument-of-multiple-trig?noredirect=1#comment9197071_4397469

Comment: Also, to answer your question, one person only moves along the circle (either clockwise OR counterclockwise), while the other person only walks towards the point at which they will meet in a straight line.

Answer (score 2):

Let's say you are on the bottom of the circle, and your friend on top, both with velocity v=wr arbitrary. (Where r denotes the radius of the circle and w the angular velocity you and your friend have).

Then your friends positions fixing the center of the circle as origin of coordinates, can be described as:
\begin{equation}
y_1= r \cos{wt} \\
x_1=-r \sin{wt}
\end{equation}

And yours, if you follow a straight with angle $\theta$ line from the bottom, will be:
\begin{equation}
 y_2=-r+v\sin{\theta}=-r+wr\sin{\theta} \\
 x_2=-v\cos{\theta}=-wr\cos{\theta}
\end{equation}

So solving the system of two equations and two variables ($\theta$ and time):
\begin{equation}
 \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ y_1=y_2 \ \ \ \ \  \cos{wt} =-1+w\sin{\theta} \\
 x_1=x_2 \ \ \ \ \  \sin{wt} = w\cos{\theta}
\end{equation}

will give you the time when you will meet, and the angle at which you will have to move.

(Just watch out how much bigger v is compared to r, because the definition of Angles for $x_2$ and $y_2$ might change depending on the quadrant of the circle where you will finally meet)

Comment: I happened to think it through myself before anyone got to the question. Here's what I got:

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4397469/physical-model-how-do-you-solve-for-a-variable-in-the-argument-of-multiple-trig?noredirect=1#comment9197071_4397469